How can I fix GNOME after a failed upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS?
I am currently able to use my computer because I am using LXQt and LightDM.
Yesterday I attempted to upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. Unfortunately the upgrade had some errors. After restarting my PC, I was greeted by this white error screen.

I then booted into rescue mode and installed lightdm. I was then able to access the login screen, but I could not log in to GNOME since the white error screen would appear again. I then installed LXDE and I was able to log in. I am now using LXQt. I would like to fix GNOME since it has my GNOME keyring on it and other settings. I would also like to use Wayland again since I get better graphical performance when playing video games on this PC. I am using a Radeon RX 580 Series GPU and no proprietary drivers are in use.
I am now going to put some system information in this post:
eric@custom:~$ uname -r
6.8.0-35-generic

eric@custom:~$ env | grep XDG
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-lxqt:/etc/xdg:/etc:/usr/share
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session2
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=lxqt-
XDG_DATA_HOME=/home/eric/.local/share
XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/home/eric/.config
XDG_SEAT=seat0
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=lxqt
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/eric
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=LXQt
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
XDG_CACHE_HOME=/home/eric/.cache
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
XDG_VTNR=7
XDG_SESSION_ID=c6
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/lxqt:/usr/share/gnome:/home/eric/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop

eric@custom:~$ uname -a
Linux custom 6.8.0-35-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon May 20 15:51:52 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux




I would suggest to clean install 24.04 as it is solid and stable (at least in my experience). I dual boot 24.04 with W11 on ThinkPad P15 Gen2i, and it just works without a single issue. In fact, since 6.8.0-35 generic kernel has reached the EOL, I am trying to upgrade to a higher version.

@iCantFindaGoodUsername Thanks. I did a reinstall and that fixed the system issues I had.

I installed Ubuntu 24.04 and I no longer have the system problems I posted about. I installed by erasing the disk and starting over.

Wow I really cant believe that you guys are actually recommending people wipe their entire disk and just start from scratch for any minor error.  All their data from however many years gone.  Any work or school documents, priceless pictures, projects, movies, games, music, books, and hobbies.  Forget all that, because the tech guy couldnt be bothered to try anything else.  The tech says erase everything and try again.  This is HORRIBLE advice please dont take advice from people like this.
First, dont listen to these guys and erase all your data.  Completely formatting and reinstalling is a LAST resort, never a FIRST one.  At the very least, I would say boot off a live DVD or live flash drive, mount your previous disk, and save all your data before you format for any reason.  But in all but the worst cases formatting is completely unnecessary.
I have experienced countless failed upgrades in both Linux and Windows and the solution is usually to simply restart the upgrade.  I have always had the best success upgrading from some type of media like a DVD or flash drive rather than upgrading from the package manager.  My advice would be to download the image and create a boot DVD or flash drive, the image is located here.
https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop
I see Ubuntu 24.04 is now too big to fit on a single DVD drive and I think that is a bad idea by Canonical.  However if you want to use a CD, DVD or small flash drive, you can use the Ubuntu Minimal iso, which is less than 250 MB.  Once it installs, then you can download and install additional packages from apt.
https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/minimal/releases/noble/release/
Either one will boot you into a usable linux environment running completely from the image.  From there you can both save any important data from your previous install, and re-try the upgrade this time from the image which usually works better.
To backup your data you will need to mount the old drive and store the data on perhaps a flash drive or external hard drive.  Here is a site talking about how to do this.
http://levlafayette.com/node/672
What I personally usually do is boot from a live DVD or flash drive.  Yes DVD's still work better than flash drives but...  Fads...  The process should be nearly identical for both DVD's and flash drives.  But for flash drives you might have to play around in your BIOS and know exactly which USB port to use to get the computer to boot.  Once it boots, install gparted with
sudo apt install gparted

Find which partition has all your old data and mount it somewhere.  If your old disk were something like sda3, make a folder and mount the disk there maybe something like this.
mkdir oldData
sudo mount /dev/sda3 oldData
cd oldData/home/username

That assumes most of your data is in your home directory, but any directory would work the same.  I would then plugin an external drive something like this
https://www.amazon.com/Seagate-Portable-External-Hard-Drive/dp/B07CRG94G3
And copy all my stuff there using something like
rsync --aHv --progress ~/oldData/home/username /media/username/Seagate Backup Drive/

And now you no longer have to worry about catastrophic data loss.  Copying to an NFS also works, putting the data on a separate flash drive also works.  You could create a backup image of the entire partition using dd.  Hell even emailing important files to your gmail account is better than nothing.   Depending on how much data you have that could take a couple hours, but if you let it run it should be fine unless the disk is damaged somehow.
Once your backup finishes, I would attempt to run the upgrade again.  A clean install will completely wipe your disk and you should avoid this at all costs.  An upgrade will preserve all your old setup and data, plus you have a backup on your external drive in case of emergency.  The upgrade screen sometimes changes slightly between versions but if you are sure to click on "upgrade" on the same partition as the old version instead of "clean install" it should work.  Do not format the partition when you are given the choice.  I have been using Ubuntu since version 6.06 when it first became popular in 2006.  This is how I prefer to upgrade and it always gives me less problems than running the upgrade from the package manager.
I have also seen a lot of so called "techs" at the Apple store just telling people to erase everything and reinstall because they cant be bothered or dont know how to help recover the old data.  Dont fall for it, it takes a little more time and a little more effort but recovery is usually completely possible.  If you need help from a "just erase everything" tech, tell him explicitly to back up your old data to an external disk, then attempt the upgrade and you do NOT want all your data erased.  It should be possible in all but the most difficult of circumstances.
Good luck!

Had you read the question properly, you'd know that the OP is asking to recover the unbootable device and hasn't mentioned a thing about the data (loss) at all which leads to the obvious assumption that the OP is not concerned about the data. Had the OP mentioned about the data, people posting solutions (including me) would have suggested to first save/backup the data and then wipe out the SSD/Disk.  And moreover, unlike windows, it's always a better idea to clean install any new Linux distro/distro version to prevent package conflicts. :))

Yea you are the type of guy I was talking about.  Whatever computer you "fix" you will basically delete all their data like "just start over."  Only there are very few people with no data on their computer that they would like to save.  Any real IT guy can tell you this.  Don't let "just erase everything" guy touch your computer.  Find someone who can backup your data for you.  An hour, dd, and an external hard drive can completely save you from catastrophic data loss.  I don't assume that people are OK with losing everything on their computer.

Hilarious.
The OP doesn't have any data on the device which is quite clear from the question. And the "just erase everything" or "just start over" is the contextual solution when getting the thing working is the (only) priority.
So, considering that, the simplest solution that I gave is the one to use in this CONTEXT.
Well, had the OP prioritized data first, I'd have suggested the OP the complex solution that you gave which is not needed for the OP's situation.

Getting the thing working is not the only priority.  The priority is that the person can USE the thing.  And this at the very least seems to me like there is data he wants to keep

"I would like to fix GNOME since it has my GNOME keyring on it and other settings. I would also like to use Wayland again since I get better graphical performance when playing video games on this PC."
That is stuff they want to keep.  How about this context.  There isnt much a person can do on a blank computer.  Yes they want the computer to work, they also want the DATA they work with to be there.

But he did reinstall or as you said, did the "just start over" and didn't seem to worry much about the trade off. Not everything needs a complex solution. In fact, it is about making the process simpler and straightforward with a few exceptions. And in this context, as you highlighted, "I would like to fix GNOME since it has my GNOME keyring on it and other settings. I would also like to use Wayland again since I get better graphical performance when playing video games on this PC." doesn't weight much to not let go as a trade off - quite a point that can be easily deduced, don't you think?

Rarely if at all do people mind losing all their data.  Maybe this guy did, maybe he didnt.   Either way, erasing all data on a persons computer is a LAST resort, never a FIRST.  You, and all your friends that agree with you, stay the hell away from my computers I dont want my data erased.  And anybody that needs help, stay away from this kind of guy he will unrepentantly erase all your data.
You do NOT have to erase everything and start over for every little error.  This guy just cant be bothered to figure out the right way to do things.  Erase and reinstall guy.  Please go away.

I completely agree with whatever you said as they are facts. I apologize if I offended you (in anyway). I wouldn't have suggested starting over unless the OP explicitly prioritized data.
Have a great day or evening or whatever it is in your timezone. :))
